# Shorten URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-shortener

I need to shorten urls like this using my htaccess file.

> http://example.org/product/category/my-product/

to

> http://example.org/my-product

how would I go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!product/category/).+)$ /product/category/$1 [L,NC]
```